# How to mark data "historic" and store them in different table

Tags: mysql, sql, move

Because I have a lot of traffic on my webpage, which has an online chat my mysql table "messages" is overcrowded. I didn't want to delete the data using a TIMESTAMPDIFF, but I wanted to move them to a "historic" table. Is there anyway to move them to the historic table after 10Minutes (600s)?

```
<!DOCTYPE
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="test.php">
<label for="firstname">First name:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Report Abduction" name="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

HTML (test) file

```
<html>
<head>
  </head>
<body>

<?php
include("delete.php");
$first_name = $_POST['firstname'];

$dbc = mysqli_connect ('localhost','julianbuchel','****','deletecontent')
or die("Ooops, we couldn't connect to the database...");


$query = "INSERT INTO messages 
VALUES ('$first_name')";



if (!mysqli_query($dbc,$query)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($dbc));
}

mysqli_close($dbc);


echo 'Thanks';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP (test) file

```
<?php
    $server = 'localhost';
    $user = 'julianbuchel';
    $password = '******';

    $link = mysql_connect($server,$user,$password);
    $db = mysql_select_db('test');
    $ssql = "DELETE FROM messages";
    $r = mysql_query($ssql, $use);
?>
```

Comment: How about a cron job? Otherwise, upon request, but that won't be accurate to 10 minutes, but >= 10 minutes, and potentially called quite often.

Comment: your code is vulnerable for SQL-Injections.

Comment: Just [set triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) to do what you want on every insert/update... see my answer for further details

Comment: cron job is a good idea! what do I insert into the shell when I entered sudo crontab -u root -e then I press i to insert the time when it 'goes off'. How do I say that it executes a script every 10 Minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks to your idea. What I did is that I set up a event_schedule in my mysql database bei putting in the command

USE GLOBAL event_schedule = 'ON'

than: CREATE EVENT name_of_event 
      ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR
      DO DELETE FROM table_name

I know thats not the perfect answer to my question, but this fits perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Ondkloss's suggestion of the cron job is good (especially if you're a shell/script person).  If you're more comfortable in the database itself, MySQL does have a scheduler: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Unless I'm missing something, your DELETE statement will get rid of everything.  If your schema supports it, how about something like this (untested) statement:

```
DELETE FROM messages
WHERE message_time <= date_sub(now(), interval 10 minute)
```